# Recuperar informação combobox PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Quero inserir o conteúdo do combobox no banco de dados por POST, porém não consigo.

Aqui o trecho do combobox, que puxa os dados de uma tabela

```
    <select name="cmbtimes">
<?php
//pegando os dados
while($dados = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
     //mostrando eles (dados) em forma de options
?>
     <option value="<?$dados['id'] ?>">
         <?= $dados['time'] ?>
     </option>
<?php

}
?>
```

E depois ele vai para a página cadastrojogador.php: (o nomej é um campo de texto do form)

```
$nomej=$_POST['nomej'];
$cmbtimes=$_POST['cmbtimes'];
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO jogador(nomej, nometime) VALUES('$nomej', '$cmbtimes')");
```

Mas ele não vai ):

Comment: Aparece algum erro?

Comment: Antes de tentar inserir, tente imprimir o valor que está dentro de $cmbtimes, veja se está pegando o valor correto

Comment: No seu código você fechou a tag select com `</select>` ?

Comment: Você está conseguindo inserir o valor de nomej, mas de cmbtimes não? Ou nenhum dos dois?

Comment: Evite usar <?= ?> é uma boa praticar usar sempre <?php ?> exite

Comment: qual o method usado no cabeçalho do formulário?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltou fechar o select e colocar o sinal de igual depois da interrogação em value.

Tenta isso:

```
<select name="cmbtimes">
<?php
//pegando os dados
while($dados = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
     //mostrando eles (dados) em forma de options
?>
     <option value="<?= $dados['id'] ?>">
         <?= $dados['time'] ?>
     </option>
<?php

}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Muito possivelmente o seu cabeçalho está mal construído e a select não está fechada:

```
<form name="contactForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="cadastrojogador.php">

    <select name="cmbtimes">
<?php
//pegando os dados
while($dados = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
     //mostrando eles (dados) em forma de options
?>
     <option value="<?$dados['id'] ?>">
         <?= $dados['time'] ?>
     </option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
</form>
```

Para ter a certeza que os dados chegam ao documento, fazia a seguinte validação no cadastrojogador.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['nomej']))
{
   $nomej=$_POST['nomej'];
   $cmbtimes=$_POST['cmbtimes'];
   $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO jogador(nomej, nometime) VALUES('$nomej', '$cmbtimes')");
}
?>
```